# Deshabilitar fechas cargadas con anterioridad en Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

¿Alguien sabe cómo deshabilitar fechas cargadas con anterioridad en control datepicker? Es muy molesto que aparezca la lista de posibles fechas ya que cubre el calendario y te obliga a seleccionar algo y después seleccionar la fecha deseada en el calendario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
var date_input = $('input[name="fec_desde"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
date_input.datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    //format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    container: container,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
})
```

```html
<input class="form-control" id="fec_desde" name="fec_desde" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es colocar en el input la opción de NO autocompletar:

```html
autocomplete="off"
```

El código completo según tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```html
<input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="fec_desde" name="fec_desde" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type="text" />
```